# What is the subset of JavaScript that is targeted (output) by Google's Closure Compiler?

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler

To clarify further, I mean what parts of JavaScript are being output by the Closure compiler?

I can definitely understand if this is a moving target, due to the name of the game being code optimization, so a reference to the relevant bits of source code might be the most useful if this is the case.

Comment: What makes you think it outputs a subset at all? Its job is minifying, primarily, optionally with some optimization. That goal is unrelated to outputting a subset of language features.

Comment: Right, I understand that: the whole set is a valid subset. Thus the moving target bit.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder it's certainly a subset, when you write for the closure compiler (especially in advanced optimization mode) you have to write JavaScript in a very certain way.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: It's been a few years, but while there are things you need to do to enable/bypass optimization (`foo.bar` vs. `foo["bar"]` and such), I don't recall any *language features* that you couldn't use with CC. (And that would be input anyway, wouldn't it?) Can you give an example? *(Have to disappear, but thanks in advance.)*

Comment: @T.J.Crowder `with` for example

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: So looking at your answer, basically `with` and `eval`, with a couple of other things it may not handle well. (I should have thought of `with`...)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder well, and you can't rely on property names and have to explicitly mention it - although OP has changed the question to what the output is (should I roll back?)

Comment: I guess target can mean different things, though I generally think of it as the output in compilers. If you amend your answer to have the bit about es3/5 so you discuss both output and input, I think that will be great

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: The question was always about output (*"...what parts of JavaScript are being output by the Closure compiler?..."*). Your answer addresses output as well as input -- usefully, in my view, since input affects output.

Comment: @bbarker done .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The limitations of the closure compiler [are specified in the docs](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/limitations):

> - The Compiler only recognizes ECMAScript. ECMAScript 5 is the version of JavaScript supported almost everywhere. However the compiler also supports many of the features in ECMAScript 6. The compiler only supports official language features.
>
>   - The Compiler does not preserve comments.
> - When you use `with` the Compiler can't distinguish between a local variable and an object property of the same name, and so it renames all instances of the name.
> - The Compiler doesn't parse the string argument of `eval`(), and so it won't rename any symbols within this argument.
> - The Compiler renames functions and function parameters but does not change any strings in your code that refer to functions or parameters by name.
> - In order to rename global variables, functions, and properties correctly, the Compiler must know about all references to those globals. You must tell the Compiler about symbols that are defined outside of the code being compiled. Advanced Compilation and Externs describes how to declare external symbols.
> - Compiled code must export any symbols that uncompiled code refers to. Advanced Compilation and Externs describes how to export symbols.
> - The Compiler renames properties in Advanced mode, but it never renames strings. If you need to refer to a property with a quoted string, always use a quoted string:
> - The Compiler renames properties and variables independently
> - When you compile functions without compiling the code that calls those functions, the Compiler assumes that the functions are never called and removes them.
> - Property flattening can change meaning of the keyword this within a function.
> - Using Object.defineProperties or ES6 getter/setters: The compiler does not understand these constructs well.

### About the output

If you want to work with the result check the syntax tree - but the output of the closure compiler is ES5 or ES3, they make no guarantees about the actual features used in the output code. See [**"JavaScript supported by Closure Compiler
"**](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/JavaScript) for exact support.